# Query database and check server details

Tags: bash, api, linux, shell, sh

I have written bash script to query database and check server details.

Please let me know if the script is as per best standards:

```
if [ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" ]
then
  echo "FAIL : Put username and password"
else
  fulltoken=`curl -s --insecure -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\":\"$1\",\"password\":\"$2\"}" https://apiurl`
  echo $fulltoken | grep -q authToken > /dev/null 2>&1
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    token=`echo $fulltoken | awk -F':' '{print $8}' | awk -F',' '{print $1}' | sed 's/"//g'`
    hostname=`uname -n | awk -F'.' '{print $1}'`
    serverdetails=`curl -s --insecure -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: $token" -X GET https://apiurl`
    echo $serverdetails | grep -iq "applnId"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
      exactserverdetails=`echo $serverdetails`
      appInId=`echo $exactserverdetails | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep "applnId" | awk -F':' '{print $2}'`

        if [ -n $appInId ] && [ $appInId != "null" ]
        then
            echo "PASS"
        else
            echo "FAIL"
        fi
        echo $exactserverdetails | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep "environment_Name" | awk -F':' '{print $2}' | grep -q -e "Dev"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo "PASS"
        else
            echo "FAIL"
        fi
    else
        echo "sorry server is not present"
    fi
  else
      echo "all good"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: I don't see any database there - it looks to be querying HTTPS server(s)

Comment: It may be helpful to add comments showing approximately what you expect `$fulltoken` and `$serverdetails` to look like, given that we're not privy to your HTTPS server.  That would help validate our assumptions/observations of how those variables are subsequently used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Add a shebang line

If you want to be able to run your program without explicitly specifying the interpreter, then you should make the script executable and start the script with a `#!` line:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

#### Usage reporting

If the arguments aren't specified, *show* how to use the program (and exit with an error status):

```
if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" || [ "${3:-}" ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 <username> <password>" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

I've redirected the error message to the standard error stream, so it will be seen; and I've replaced the Bash `test -o` with a more portable alternation of `test` commands.

It's up to you whether an empty password (as opposed to an unset password) is allowable.

### Care with variable expansions

You've been pretty diligent about quotes (well done), but there is one place where you might get tripped up:

```
fulltoken=`curl ... "{\"password\":\"$2\"}" ...`
```

Could `$2` contain `"`?  If so, you might want to escape it (`${2//\"/\\\"}`) or detect it and abort before executing `curl`.

### The `if $?` antipattern

Instead of running a command and then separately testing the status, it's more idiomatic to use a single `if`:

```
if echo "$fulltoken" | grep authToken >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  ...
fi
```

A couple of further observations on this particular line: you could replace `echo` with a `<<<` redirection; you could replace the `grep` with testing against a substituted string (both of these involve Bash extensions, so you might prefer to lean towards the portability above):

```
if <<<"$fulltoken" grep -q authToken 2>/dev/null
```

```
if [ "$fulltoken" != "${fulltoken/authToken}" ]
```

Related to this is

### Keep the error handling close by

The program has more than one structure that looks like

```
if some_test
then
    ...
    lots
    ...
    of
    ...
    code
    ...
    here
    ...
    if second_test
    then
        ....
        more
        code
        ...
    else
        echo "INNER FAIL"
    fi
else
    echo "FAIL"
fi
```

This can make it harder to relate the `else` clause to the correct `if`.  My usual approach to this is to define a `die` function:

```
die(){
    echo "$@" >&2
    exit 1
}
```

Then the structure above becomes more linear and less indented:

```
some_test || die "FAIL"
...
lots
...
of
...
code
...
here
...
second_test || die "INNER FAIL"
....
more
code
...
```

This might not work for you if you want to report more than one problem per run, but it's certainly something to consider and possibly adapt for your purposes.

### Use the simplest tool for the job

Although `awk` can pick out fields from a line, that's the sole purpose of `cut`, and I think it's clearer that that's all you're doing if you write like

```
token=$(echo "$fulltoken" | cut -d: -f8 | cut -d, -f1 | tr -d \")
```

Conversely, if you use `awk`, use it fully - the `applnId` pipeline (`sed`|`grep`|`awk`) can be done with a single `awk` invocation:

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN { RS = "," } $1 == "applnId" {print $2}'
```

Note that this is now a stricter test - it won't be fooled by a value containing `applnId`, for instance; it recognises only a key of exactly `applnId`.

Actually, since you have asked for JSON output, it's easier and more reliable to use `jq` than pure Bash to parse it:

```
applnId=$(jq -r applnId <<<"$exactserverdetails")
```

Similarly, to test the environment name:

```
test "$(jq -r environment_Name <<<"$exactserverdetails")" = Dev \
    || die "Environment name is not 'Dev'"
```

### Be more specific when reporting errors

This test doesn't tell the user much:

```
    if [ -n $appInId ] && [ $appInId != "null" ]
    then
        echo "PASS"
    else
        echo "FAIL"
    fi
```

Instead, I'd write:

```
    case "${appInId-}" in
      '') echo "No applnId" >&2; exit 2;;
      null) echo "applnId is 'null'" >&2; exit 2;;
      *) echo "applnId is valid";; # (if you must)
    esac
```

I'd omit the last case, though - I'm not a fan of overly chatty programs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments so far. Can you throw some light on the following:   `        echo $exactserverdetails | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep "environment_Name" | awk -F':' '{print $2}' | grep -q -e "Dev"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
            echo "PASS"
        else
            echo "FAIL"
        fi`

Comment: okay i will try that but will also look for your comments next week